# Finding the roots of an absolute value natural log function, regarding the usage of Newton-Raphson

Tags: calculus, logarithms, approximation, cubics, newton-raphson

This is an exercise I saw in my last test, I've been practicing it but I'm currently a bit lost when finding the roots, here's the exercise:

1. Given $f:f(x)=-x^2+2x+3$, be **F/F(x)** is a primitive of **f** such as **F(3)=0**; analyze and graph the function **h:h(x)=Ln|F(x)|**.

What I did so far was integrate f(x), obtaining $F(x)=\frac{(-x^3)}{3}+x^2+3x-9$ , 9 being the constant that makes F(3)=0 possible.

From that, I proceeded with the study of $h(x)=Ln|\frac{(-x^3)}{3}+x^2+3x-9|$

Given its absolute value, after setting h(x)=0 to find the roots that pass through the x axis, I find myself with 2 equations:

$i)\frac{(-x^3)}{3}+x^2+3x-9=1$ and $ii)\frac{(-x^3)}{3}+x^2+3x-9=-1$
which, after being rearranged, end up looking like this:

$i)-x^3+3x^2+9x-30=0$ and $ii)-x^3+3x^2+9x-24=0$

So, the problem now for me would be how to find the roots of these cubic equations, the first thing that comes to mind would be Newton-Raphson to approximate the roots, but I haven't had much experience using this method which is the primary reason I came here, not for an explanation of how to use it since I already know, but more about, **HOW** to efficiently know **where** to look for the roots, I thought about just using the calculator to find the roots through the EQN mode and from there, using the integer closest to the left of the root shown in the calculator as the first $x_n$ for Newton-Raphson. Am I missing a different method? Since this is too dependent on the calculator and I'm not too used yet to "approximation" given I've always been used to fractions instead of cutting it down to a few decimals.
Edit: Forgot to mention I wasn't able to find evident roots, so I backed down on that and went back to Newton-Raphson.

That said, any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Moo F(x) is the integral of f(x)

Comment: To find the roots, yes, given I wasn't able to find evident roots for (i) and (ii) equations, I wanted an accurate way to find the roots but in this case it seems like my only way is approximation right? But as far as I know Newton's method is best used for finding one root, not multiple roots as is the case for (ii) which has 3 roots. Did some research by myself and found out there's a modified version of Newton's method, Halley's method, which could find multiple roots apparently, that said however, am I headed the right way?Because I wouldn't be surprised if I'm missing something very basic

Comment: The repeated roots are complex numbers right? Given I have only worked with real numbers this year this time they are not needed, in that modified Newton Method what does n stand for? Multiplicity of the root?

Comment: @Moo regarding that last point, maybe you misread the original equation, but there's a Ln besides the abs, that's why when h(x) is set to 0, the e from Ln goes to interact with the 0 to the right as $e^0=1$, that's why $|\frac{(-x^3)}{3}+x^2+3x-9|=1$ and therefore it breaks down as both abs=1 and abs=-1.
Using the calculator I can find that when abs=-1 it has 3 roots, which is the problem I wanted to solve here, as in, if there was a more efficient method to approach this or Newton Method was the best for it, and the second question would be, besides using a calculator, how would I find (1/2)

Comment: In what intervals are the multiple roots located? As in, a way to quickly leave a registry of it without depending on a calculator to locate the closest integer to the roots, or that's the only way? I apologize if I come off as a bit hard to understand, since those were the main concerns I wanted to approach.

Comment: I know there are four roots: 1 root from the abs=1 and 3 from the abs=-1
It's more of a me problem with understanding how to find the intervals to look for the roots with Newton's Method, I quote "not for an explanation of how to use it since I already know, but more about, HOW to efficiently know where to look for the roots, I thought about just using the calculator to find the roots through the EQN mode and from there, using the integer closest to the left of the root shown in the calculator as the first $x_n$ for Newton-Raphson"

Comment: Maybe with a question I can portray my concern better:
"So, how did you know to look at these intervals for z, x, and y roots?"
Would I answer with "I looked the roots in the calculator and then locked onto the closest integer to x root, and from there I applied Newton's Method"? or "I made a huge table with x as an input and h(x) as the output and looked at the numbers that crossed from negative to positive to find the roots", even I am questioning myself whether what I'm saying makes any sense right now, but that's the gist of it, since it's quite the opposite to how I'm used to do math